# Reusing a partial in the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller with 3 objects and i want to call the same partial three time with each object

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @evaluations_teams = Evaluation.eager_load(:user).where(users: {status: true}).where(team_id: current_user.student_details.last.team_id).all.order(created_at: :desc).limit 5

        @evaluations_stage = Evaluation.eager_load(:user).where(users: {status: true}).where(stage_id: current_user.student_details.last.stage_id).all.order(created_at: :desc).limit 5

        @evaluations_schools = Evaluation.eager_load(:user).where(users: {status: true}).where(school_id: current_user.student_details.last.school_id).all.order(created_at: :desc).limit 5
    end
end
```

INDEX.HTML.ERB

```
<%= render 'home/partials/loop_areas', locals: {evaluations:@evaluations_teams} %>

<%= render 'home/partials/loop_areas', locals: {evaluations:@evaluations_stage} %>

<%= render 'home/partials/loop_areas', locals: {evaluations:@evaluations_schools} %>
```

Partial: home/partials/_loop_areas.html.erb

```
<% @evaluations.each do |evaluation| %>
<div class="div-card-infosaluno">
    <div class="card-aluno"><%= evaluation.user.full_name %></div>
    <div class="card-serie"><%= "#{evaluation.stage.name} · #{evaluation.school.name}" %></div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

This returns:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

on <% @evaluations.each do |evaluation| %>

How can i do this?

Comment: Try to remove the `@` in @evaluations.

Comment: Returns: undefined local variable or method `evaluations' for

Comment: Another way to call the partial is `<%= render 'home/partials/loop_areas', evaluations: @evaluations_teams %>`. Without the `locals`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access an instance variable `@evaluations` in your partial but it is not defined in the controller action.

You've to instead loop through the local variable `evaluations`.

```
<%# home/partials/_loop_areas.html.erb %>

<% evaluations.each do |evaluation| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And your view should be

```
<%= render 'home/partials/loop_areas', evaluations: @evaluations_teams %>

<%= render 'home/partials/loop_areas', evaluations: @evaluations_stage %>

<%= render 'home/partials/loop_areas', evaluations: @evaluations_schools %>
```

You can also pass a hash to the `render` method but I feel it is more verbose.

```
<%= render partial: 'home/partials/loop_areas', locals: { evaluations: @evaluations_schools } %>
```

Comment: This returns the error: undefined local variable or method `evaluations' for

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below code in Partial: home/partials/_loop_areas.html.erb

It should work as you are expecting.

```
    <% evaluations = local_assigns[:evaluations] %>

    <% evaluations.each do |evaluation| %>
    <div class="div-card-infosaluno">
        <div class="card-aluno"><%= evaluation.user.full_name %></div>
        <div class="card-serie"><%= "#{evaluation.stage.name} · #{evaluation.school.name}" %></div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

Thanks.